# Find path containing point

Tags: postgis, postgresql

In Postgres with PostGIS extension, I try to figure out to find the path containing a specific point:

- table A contains POINT
- table B contains PATH

My code returns `0 rows` when it should

```sql
select * from A join B on ST_Contains(A.coordinates::geometry, B.coordinates::geometry);
```

I also tried to inverse A in B, without success. For the both tables `ST_IsValid(coordinate::geometry)` return `true`

Comment: Just modify `ST_CONTAINS` with `ST_INTERSECTS`.

Comment: yes, thanks, I've also tried, without success.

Comment: But for me `SELECT ST_INTERSECTS(ST_MAKEPOINT(10, 47), path('(10, 47)')::geometry);` gives me `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in fact very hard to determine if a point is exactly - or not - on a line, because the coordinates have 15 decimals, which are just noise unless you specifically mention them.

What you could do is to look for points that are very very close to the line

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
  join B on ST_DWithin(A.coordinates::geometry, B.coordinates::geometry,0.0001);
```

The distance specified in `st_dwithin` uses the source coordinate system, so you would have to adjust it (meters, degrees etc)

Comment: It's perfect and works fine !